# List is empty of transactional emails template by default

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, configuration, email, email-templates

I am working on ver 1.9.1 and by default the list of "transactional email template" is empty causing my store to not able to send any emails. Are there anyways to import them or get them?

thanks[image]

Comment: That is not how the templates work. That list being empty has nothing to do with your store not sending emails.

Comment: @mbalparda then what can be the other reasons for mails not sending. all settings are configured correctly both in backend and admin. However, I don't have the folder named "template" under app\locale\en_US . any clue ?

Comment: You have to check your installed extensions.
I had the same problem and disabling my plugin one by one I discovered that one was creating the issue. Disabling it I found the drop down list populated.

Answer (score 1):

this list will be empty by default and will be populated only once you CUSTOMIZE transactional emails.

you want to click the "Add New Template" to create a custom template and follow the steps there.

Ad far as emails not sending, go to Configuration => system

make sure "Disable email communication " is set to "No" and that all information is entered properly.

HTH

Comment: what can be other reasons for mails not sending. admin settings are configured properly, mail server is configured properly. however, I don't have the folder named "template" under app\locale\en_US . any clue ?